# Spreadsheet::WriteExcel Memory Usage

Tags: perl, excel, memory

I'm trying to create a multi-sheet excel document, and thus far I'd been doing it in PHP - but using PHPExcel was eating up 70MB of RAM for about 60,000 spreadsheet cells total.

I'm wondering if anyone has experience with Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and if it has problems with creating very large documents.

I'd just give it a shot but I'm very inexperienced with Perl and it could take me quite a bit of time to get this up and rolling even if for a test, and I thought someone here might have insight for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it should be OK for you.  From the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#set_tempdir%28%29), it looks like Spreadsheet::WriteExcel will manage memory for you so long as it can use a temporary directory.

On the other hand if it's just data you need, and you don't need presentation or formulae, then I'd recommend writing to CSV using [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/search?mode=module;query=Text%3A%3ACSV_XS).  In this case the code you end up writing will be much much simpler.